# Iterating a List of Hashmap which is also a list of hashmap Using jstl

Tags: java, jsp, foreach

Consider the iteration below: `requestScope.scriptdataset` is of type

`List<HashMap<String, List<HashMap<String, Object>>>>`

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<c:forEach var="objdatatable" items="${requestScope.scriptdataset}">

<c:if test="${not empty objdatatable['vwcmstreevwdata']}">
<c:forEach var="objrecord" items="${objdatatable['vwcmstreevwdata']}">

<c:forEach var="record" items="${objrecord}">

<c:out value="${record['ChildName']}"/>

</c:forEach>

</c:forEach>

</c:if>

</c:forEach>
```

I want to get the value of the innermost hashmap by key but it is failing as shown below.

> May 17, 2014 8:51:16 PM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher
>   invoke SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
>   javax.el.PropertyNotFoundException: Property 'ChildName' not found on
>   type java.util.HashMap$Entry  at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.get(BeanELResolver.java:266)
>     at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver$BeanProperties.access$300(BeanELResolver.java:243)
>     at javax.el.BeanELResolver.property(BeanELResolver.java:353)    at
>   javax.el.BeanELResolver.getValue(BeanELResolver.java:97)  at
>   org.apache.jasper.el.JasperELResolver.getValue(JasperELResolver.java:104)
>     at org.apache.el.parser.AstValue.getValue(AstValue.java:183)    at
>   org.apache.el.ValueExpressionImpl.getValue(ValueExpressionImpl.java:184)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.proprietaryEvaluate(PageContextImpl.java:967)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menudetails_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fout_005f0(menudetails_jsp.java:221)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menudetails_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f2(menudetails_jsp.java:190)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menudetails_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f1(menudetails_jsp.java:150)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menudetails_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(menudetails_jsp.java:110)
>     at
>   org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menudetails_jsp._jspService(menudetails_jsp.java:72)
>     at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
>     at
>   org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
>     at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDo

In the code shown above if change   `<c:out value="${record['ChildName']}"/>` to `<c:out value="${record}"/>`
It is displaying all data of the inner list which assures me that the iteration is okay but how should I get the values of the inner hashmap by key. Any assistance will be greatly appreciated.

**EDIT**

In the code above

if I change`<c:out value="${record['ChildName']}"/>` to `<c:out value="${record.key}"/>`

it displays all keys

if I change`<c:out value="${record['ChildName']}"/>` to `<c:out value="${record.value}"/>`

it displays all values

if I change`<c:out value="${record['ChildName']}"/>` to

`<c:forEach var="entry" items="${record}" >`

`<c:out value="${entry.key}"/>`

`</c:forEach>`

it complains:

```
May 18, 2014 10:02:16 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher invoke
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet jsp threw exception
javax.servlet.jsp.JspTagException: Don't know how to iterate over supplied "items" in &lt;forEach&gt;
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.toForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:312)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.supportedTypeForEachIterator(ForEachSupport.java:276)
    at org.apache.taglibs.standard.tag.common.core.ForEachSupport.prepare(ForEachSupport.java:193)
    at javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.core.LoopTagSupport.doStartTag(LoopTagSupport.java:291)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menudetails_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f3(menudetails_jsp.java:226)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menudetails_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f2(menudetails_jsp.java:190)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menudetails_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f1(menudetails_jsp.java:150)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menudetails_jsp._jspx_meth_c_005fforEach_005f0(menudetails_jsp.java:110)
    at org.apache.jsp.WEB_002dINF.views.menudetails_jsp._jspService(menudetails_jsp.java:72)
    at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:432)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:390)
    at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:334)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:727)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the code FROM

```
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<c:forEach var="objdatatable" items="${requestScope.scriptdataset}">

<c:if test="${not empty objdatatable['vwcmstreevwdata']}">
<c:forEach var="objrecord" items="${objdatatable['vwcmstreevwdata']}">

<c:forEach var="record" items="${objrecord}">

<c:out value="${record['ChildName']}"/>

</c:forEach>

</c:forEach>

</c:if>

</c:forEach>
```

TO

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>

<c:forEach var="objdatatable" items="${requestScope.scriptdataset}">

<c:if test="${not empty objdatatable['vwcmstreevwdata']}">
<c:forEach var="objrecord" items="${objdatatable['vwcmstreevwdata']}">

<c:out value="${objrecord['ChildName']}"/>

</c:forEach>

 </c:if>

</c:forEach>
```

and It is working. Members of "Anti-JSP Scriptlets" camp-proponents of JSTL must must explain.
Thanks.